# Python: if element1 from list1 is equal to element2 from list2, change element1

Tags: python, list, element

This is part of a homework for my 'Basics of Programming' course at UNI.
It says:

> write down a `codes(lst,cods)` function, where `lst` is a series of strings in `ccccyyyymmgg` (`cccc` are random characters, `yyyymmgg` is a date) and `cods` is a series of 4-characters strings.
>
> The function should work like this:
>   if a 'cccc' in lst is equal to a string in cods, the element that contains the cccc is printed in the format ['cccc', dd, mm, yyyy]; otherwise is printed in the format ['ccccyyyymmdd'] .
>
> For example, 
>   if `"AcDa20140930"` is an element of `lst` and `"ACDA"` is on `cods`, 
>   then the element `"AcDa20140930"` in the list `lst` is replaced with the 4 elements 
>   `"ACDA", 30, 9, 2014`.

I tried to solve it like this:

```
def codes(lst, cods):
    lst1=[]
    for element in lst:
        cccc = lst[0:3]
        yyyy = lst[4:7]
        mm = lst[8:9]
        dd = lst[10:11]
        for code in cods:
            if cccc == code:
                lst1 += cccc, dd, mm, yyyy
    return lst1

first = ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']
secnd = ['PALA', 'CARA', 'Tara']
print codes(first, secnd)
```

[CODE MODIFIED]: now the output is [] . 
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a more meaningful problem statement than *"it doesn't work"*? Also, is that *really* the homework you were given? It does not seem well written.

Comment: actually...there's no output. When I execute the program with 
python program.py 
, the shell only shows the cursor until i interrupt, then:

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 38, in <module>
    print codes(first, secnd)
  File "program.py", line 29, in codes
    lst.remove(element)
KeyboardInterrupt


-----
I know; it is NOT well written, but that's what the teacher wrote..

Comment: Why don't you throw a `print lst` into the inner loop and see what's happening? Also, note that e.g. `cccc = element[:4]` (look up "slice") is much neater than your current approach.

Comment: if you mean like this http://pastebin.com/NAHLjduA
the output is ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']

Comment: Well that doesn't run forever, and uses different inputs...

Comment: sorry for the inputs :P i took the ones i actually used for the first test...

Comment: at least it doesn't run forever lol

Comment: Then perhaps you should try it **with the failing inputs** and `print` what's happening there. Have a look at http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I had tried with the failing inputs...and the output is what i wrote in the previous comment

Comment: Sorry for the annoying question, too, but i got stuck and really need a help...

Comment: So it never reaches `print lst`? What if you move that line somewhere else in the loop? Be aware that you're modifying a list while iterating over it, a notoriously terrible idea.

Comment: no: it reaches 'print lst'...but it doesn't print the list that i want.
the output is:['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']

Comment: Please read that link on debugging, and see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist. Unless you can come up with a consistent, minimal code sample and clear description of the problem, you should remove this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works.

### Solution #1:

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/0vg/12)[Edited]

#### Code:

```
def codes(lst, cods):

    toAdd = []
    c = 0
    for ind, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if elem[:4] not in cods:
            toAdd.append(elem + str(ind + c))
            lst.remove(elem)
            c += 1
    for ind, elem in enumerate(lst):
        tmp = []
        tmp.append(elem[:4])
        tmp.append(elem[10:])
        tmp.append(elem[8:10])
        tmp.append(elem[4:8])
        lst.insert(ind, tmp)
        lst.remove(elem)
    [lst.insert(int(elem[-1]), elem[:len(elem) - 1]) for elem in toAdd]

    return lst

first = ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']
secnd = ['PALA', 'CARA', 'Tara']
print codes(first, secnd)
```

#### Output:

```
['Cara20130716', ['Tara', '01', '06', '2008'], ['PALA', '31', '12', '1996'], 'Melo19601023']
```

---

### Solution #2:

If you want the match to be case-insensitive.

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/0vg/11)

#### Code:

```
def codes(lst, cods):

    for ind, cod in enumerate(cods):
        cods[ind] = cod.lower()
    toAdd = []
    c = 0
    for ind, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if elem[:4].lower() not in cods:
            toAdd.append(elem + str(ind+c))
            lst.remove(elem)
            c += 1
    for ind, elem in enumerate(lst):
        tmp = []
        tmp.append(elem[:4])
        tmp.append(elem[10:])
        tmp.append(elem[8:10])
        tmp.append(elem[4:8])
        lst.insert(ind, tmp)
        lst.remove(elem)
    [lst.insert(int(elem[-1]), elem[:len(elem) - 1]) for elem in toAdd]

    return lst

first = ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']
secnd = ['PALA', 'CARA', 'Tara']
print codes(first, secnd)
```

#### Output:

```
[['Cara', '16', '07', '2013'], ['Tara', '01', '06', '2008'], ['PALA', '31', '12', '1996'], 'Melo19601023']
```

Comment: almost there. The only missing thing: i need to print the other elements of 'first', too.
if elem not in cods, it should print it as it comes in 'first'.
so the output should be [['Dear20130716'],['Pear','01','06','2008']...etc]